# Fancy Heading for chapter, instead of the word "Chapter"

Tags: formatting

I made a kind of dictionary of some subject. I ordered the concepts alphabetically. What I would like to achieve is to put some "heading" to each letter. If I use `\chapter{J}` I obtain: "Chapter 1" "J" etc. I would like to show a stylished letter instead (gothic or something alike), without the word "Chapter", but in the table of contents, I would want it to appear as J. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with one of the `cfr-initials` fonts and `titlesec`. Here is a possible code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{GoudyIn}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\color{Coral3}\fontsize{48}{60}\selectfont}{\GoudyInfamily\thechapter}{0pt}{}
\chapter{}

\lipsum[11]

\chapter{}

\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you Bernard!